# Cannot find name 'AnimationPlayer'

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, ionic2, visual-studio-cordova

I have followed [**this article**](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic2/#requirements) and tried to create an Ionic2 app. I can compile a project.But when I try to run it where it shows below errors.Can you tell me how to solve them?

[image]

It shows error on this path : `\WeatherAppIonic2\node_modules\@angular\core\src\animation\animation_group_player.d.ts`

I have selected a platform as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh... I have found the solution for this.

**Just close the Solution and Reopen it again :D**